# Why are my Events in iOS 8 iPhoto in a completely random order?

Tags: photos.app, photos, ios, mobile-iphoto

Since upgrading to iOS 8, I've noticed that the Events list inside iPhoto is no longer in reverse chronological order. In fact, it's not in any order at all. This makes the Events system almost completely useless for me.

Is anyone else experiencing this? Is it a bug, or is there a setting I need to configure?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug.
No fix at all right now.

I've tried all the usual suspects, re-order in iPhoto, delete & re-add all my Events, clear & re-sync everything.

Events arrive in random order whatever I do… a different random order after each of the attempts to fix.

There's been a lot of discussion on the Apple community site about it, no-one's found a fix, the bug is known to have been reported already.

Answer (score 0):

in itunes, when you click to add photos you will see it ask if you want all, some, or recent.. click events and add one event at a time. start with the event you want to show first, then add the event you want to add second etc etc. it seems they put events in the order the pictures are placed on the device. so even tho you have them set up in order via the list in itunes, it syncs all the photos randomly putting the events in order they are sent to the device.